# Creating a form/search box to pass a search word into a query string to be used with rails scope params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a search box (form) that when submitted will pass the search_word into the query string.

```
<%= link_to articles_path(title: "search_word") %>

class Article < Active Record::Base
  scope :title, -> (title) { where("title ILIKE ?", "%#{title}%")}
end

class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index 
    @articles = Article.all
    @articles = @articles.title(params[:title]) if params[:title].present? 
  end
end
```

This will allow the User to use the search box to search the articles by title.

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea here is that you must provide a form for the user to enter data and submit it to your app.

In your view, change this:

```
<%= link_to articles_path(title: "search_word") %>
```

into this form:

```
<%= form_tag articles_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "title", params[:title], placeholder: "Search by title" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

The `form_tag` is passed the path of the controller#action that will handle the search. Then a text field is created to allow the user to type in a search term - this value will be available in your controller via `params[:title]`. We give the text field `params[:title]` as a second argument so that it will display any previous search term the user may have typed in. The `placeholder:` let's the user know what attribute the articles will be searched by. Finally, a `submit_tag` is created to allow the user to submit the form.

P.S Note form is of GET type so whatever the value user typed in will be available as query params in url. So if you wanna bookmark search results then it can be possible.

Comment: this works however the following is being shown as the placeholder....  {:value=>nil, :placeholder=>"Search by title"} ...not "Search by title"...

Comment: Oops, I got my APIs mixed up, remove the 'value:' part so that the second argument is just 'params[:title]'

Comment: please see this topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130833/using-will-paginate-while-applying-a-scope-with-params-to-the-model - a similar question to this topic.