# Using will_paginate while applying a scope with params to the Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am attempting to create a search box that can be used to search User's by their name. The problem I am running into is that I also want to use the will_paginate gem. This line of code `@users = User.name(params[:name]).paginate(page: params[:page]) if params[:name].present?` is where I think the problem lies.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def index
  @users = User.all.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @users = User.name(params[:name]).paginate(page: params[:page]) if params[:name].present? 
end 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :name, -> (name) { where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{name}%")} 
end

users/index.html.erb

  <%= form_tag users_path, method: :get do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name], :placeholder => "Search by name" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search"%>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: You haven't stated what your problem is.

Comment: The app crashes with this code. I cannot open any of the pages. All I get from Heroku is:  `State changed from starting to crashed.  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"`

Comment: That error can't be caused by runtime level code, you might have a syntax error somewhere in class level code that's crashing your app on boot up. Do you have a Procfile? Can you boot up your app locally using the same command as your Procfile's web: declaration?

Comment: I guess I figured it out. I can't use :name for the scope. When I changed it, it worked. Not sure why. Using :title worked for my other model but that model did not include will_paginate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:name cannot be used as the scope. When I changed it to :namesearch the code worked.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :nameseach, -> (name) { where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{name}%")} 
end

def index
  @users = User.all.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @users = User.namesearch(params[:name]).paginate(page: params[:page]) if params[:name].present? 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in line one of your controller file. The super class has a space in it "Application Controller"

That would cause a boot time H10 error on Heroku.

Comment: that was just an error i made when typing up the question. something is wrong with the code.